# Dutch 'visioneren' in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

In Belgium, "visioneren" is the Dutch word for the process of "approving video material before usage in broadcast". This is done by the director, or someone else working for television/the movies, to quickly weed out those filmed clips that do not meet a certain standard.

This process happens after filming (=at this point there is lots and lots of material) and before editing (=at this point everything that is truly unusable for the final movie/episode/... is taken out).
Meaning that when the actual movie is put together, the editor is not distracted by "the really bad stuff". It's possibly that "visioneren" is in fact the first thing done by the editor: throwing away everything that can not possibly have a good impact on the final product.

Possible things that the "visioneren"-process could take out:
- **Poor lighting**: The clip is so dark or so overlighted that it cannot be used
- **Something inscreen**: A mic got in screen in this clip. Throw it away so this does not end up in the final product.
- **Poor content**: Something that might have seemed a good idea during filming but now it appears that the clip does not contribute to the story, is not funny etc, so it's thrown away
- Anything really that makes the one doing the "visioneren" think: If this is put in, it will make for a worse show/movie.

In Dutch:
"Standaardtaal in België voor: keuren voor vertoning of uitzending."
http://www.vrt.be/taal/visioneren

Is there an English equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "pre-screen."  Go [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-18798060):

> China's websites must **pre-screen** all videos under new censorship
>   rules from its broadcasting regulator.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same thing, "visioneren" is not done for censorship but rather for the director to split between "can use (for broadcast)" and "throw away" (we can't use this, the quality of the video or content is too low) video clips.

Comment: @Laoujin: *pre-screening* can be done ***either*** for censorship ***or*** for quality control.

Comment: When "visioneren" is done, there is not yet a movie to show to someone. There are just hours and hours of clips that have not yet been assembled into something that can be pre-screened.

Answer (score 2):

**To vet** is defined by Merriam-Webster as "to check (something) carefully to make sure it is acceptable".

Comment: "Visioneren" is not a careful process. It's a quick process to split clips into two categories "might use" and "will not use".

Answer (score 0):

The nearest term I can think for this is "proofreading." For several years I was employed by a small-town newspaper as a proofreader. That is basically the last step in the checks-and-balances before the copy goes to press.
I don't know how close "visioneren" for film compares to "proofreader" for printed medium, but it pretty much seems to be the last visual quality-control checkpoint for each.

Answer (score 0):

**Fine Cut:** The fine cut is the phase after the *assembly edit* and the *rough cut* [rough organiztion of scenes] stage. In this stage the music is finalised and an EDL is created to log the scenes. Overall, you eliminate any extraneous scenes or lines of dialogue and fix anything else that isn't working.

Comment: If 10 hours is filmed, the "visioneren"-process filters out for example 3 hours that is just "bad" (bad lightning, overacting, something inscreen that shouldn't be there, ...). Both the original movie and the director's cut are taken from the "good" parts of the visioneren-process.

Comment: So something like: total filmed: 10 hours material. After "visioneren": 7 hours left. Director's cut: 2 hours. Final cut: 1h40min...